# How to add colour to the text in a paragraph

Tags: asp.net

my question is about adding colour to the text in my paragraph.
I want to add the colour white.
I have tried adding  tags in the beginning of the paragraph, but it doesn't work. 
How do I do that?

Comment: Have you used CSS styles to change the colour?

Comment: as in ' <p style="font:700px; font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:30px; color:whitesmoke; Background:black; opacity:0.4;"> '

Answer (score 0):

If you want to color an html parahraph, you will need CSS.

You can do it inline: `<p style="color:white">Lorem ipsum</p>`

Or between style tags inside the `<head>` element:

```
<style> p { color: white; } </style>
```

Or in a separate CSS file:

```
p { color: white; }
```

In that case, you will need to reference the CSS file in the html like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

Comment: Update: I have used the following, <p style="font:700px; font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:30px; color:whitesmoke; Background:black; opacity:0.4;">. The problem I'm facing is that, i want the opacity to be for the background only.Not the text.

Comment: Add the opacity to the parent element's style attribute, like this:

`<div style="opacity: 0.4"><p style="opacity: 1">Lorem ipsum</p><div>`

Comment: Could you get it sorted?

Comment: i added opacity to the parent's element but that lead to letting the whole page being with opacity 0.4

Comment: Wrap a `<div>` or `<span>` around it, and set the opacity for that element.

Comment: you mean a big div and set opacity for that, then in that, another div which contains <p>